# Python double double quotes not being replaced

Tags: python, dataframe, python-re

I have a list of strings in a dataframe and would like to replace double double quotes "" into a single double quote " using Python. However, no matter how I try it's not getting replaced. I've tried the following:

```
text['document'] = text['document'].apply(lambda x : x.replace('\"\"', 'TEST'))
```

and

```
text['document'] = text['document'].apply(lambda x : re.sub('\"{2}', 'TEST', x))
```

Any ideas how to make it work ? Thanks in advance

Comment: please show `text['document']`

Comment: ""It\'s like having your own house.""

Comment: Where did `""` come from? Did you initially import a CSV file that uses `""` to represent a literal `"` in a quoted field?

Comment: It comes from a JSON file containing newspapers articles. Most articles have single double quotes to represent citations, but some have double double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas automatically parses the escaped double quotes and stores them as double quotes in raw. You can therefore replace them as such. Example:

```
x = pandas.DataFrame(['\"\"'])
x = x.replace('""', "TEST")
```

`x` would now have one entry that has `TEST` in it. Just make sure when you're replacing them, you're using either single quotes `'` or triple double quotes `"""` to contain the string like I did in the example.
Edit: It seems the issue is actually because example text was before loading, the actual text was loaded via json.loads meaning the outermost quotes were removed and so you simply have to replace with a single quote instead.

Comment: Thanks, but that does not work as well. I've tried many combinations of double quotes, even the curved ones “”, ““ and ””.

Comment: If your original document contained double quotes, in the JSON file, then the outermost pair likely got stripped. Try just replacing a single quote `'"'`

Comment: Interesting, when I change `'"'` to TEST it works, both `""` are changed to TEST. Not TESTTEST, only one TEST. However I'd like to replace `""` to `"` and that does not work.

Comment: When you said the text was `""It\'s like having your own house.""`, I assume you mean the original text, not the actual contents of `text['document']`. When you load your text via JSON.loads, the outermost quotes are being stripped, leaving you with `"It\'s like having your own house."`. If you print `text['document']`, you will see that all of your text has lost one pair of qoutes.

Comment: Sorry, that was coming from text['document']. I opened the JSON with notepad and the line is `\"It\'s like having your own house.\"`. But I then tried to replace `\"` but the result was inconclusive.

Comment: Okay I see. Well I'm not sure where you're finding double quotes but it seems like you were seeing them as a result of some print formatting, rather than actually in the data. As I previously mentioned, you can't replace escaped characters in pandas because it automatically removes the escapes. Therefore you can just replace `'"'`. If you want to guarantee you only have single quotes, you can do `column.strip('"')` for each column, and then `column.apply(lambda x: '"'+x+'"')`

Comment: I just found what was the problem and this has nothing to do with the JSON. It was something related to a chunk of code after loading the data. Thanks for your help though !

Comment: Gotcha. You should put what you found as an answer or in your question so that future people seeing this might find it as well in case they have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

From comments, It seems `JSON Serialization` issue ,did you try `json.loads`,

```
In [7]: import json

In [8]: text
Out[8]: '"It\'s like having your own house."'

In [9]: json.loads(text)
Out[9]: "It's like having your own house."
```

or loading json file in this way:

```
In [10]: with open('some_json_file.json','r') as f:
    ...:     data = json.load(f)
```

Comment: Yes, here's the line I used to load the text: `data = [json.loads(line) for line in open(filename, encoding="utf8")]`

Comment: Your last example does not work as I have one element for each article, hence I get the following error: `JSONDecodeError: Extra data`

Comment: I just found what was the problem and this has nothing to do with the JSON. It was something related to a chunk of code after loading the data. Thanks for your help though !